# WPF Backgroundwork er call method on DoWork event

Tags: wpf

I have a BackgroundWorker on my WPF UserControl.

```
        private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        public ucCustomer()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
          worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
          worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }
        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // run all background tasks here
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,  RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //update ui once worker complete his work
        }
        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Above code is work, the UI is response when the task is working, but if i change the worker_DoWork() to

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // run all background tasks here
   Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, 
        new Action(() => {
        gridDataBind(); //A long data-mining task,using Dispatcher.Invoke() to access UI.
    }));
} 

private void gridDataBind()
{
    SnEntities sn = new SnEntities();
    var customers = from c in sn.Customer select c;
    dgCustomer.ItemsSource = customers.ToList();
}
```

The UI is freeze until the task is end.

Is it any solution?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the ItemsSource like below code:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // run all background tasks here
    e.Result = gridDataBind(); //A long data-mining task.
}

private IList<Customer> gridDataBind()
{
    SnEntities sn = new SnEntities();
    var customers = from c in sn.Customer select c;
    return customers.ToList();
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var customers = e.Result as IList<Customer>;

        ObservableCollection<Customer> gridItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                             new Action(() =>
                             {
                                 dgCustomer.ItemsSource = gridItemsSource;
                             }));

        foreach(var customer in customers)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                 new Action(() =>
                                 {
                                     gridItemsSource.Add(customer);
                                 }));
        }

    }
```

Comment: can i just keep a single gridDatabind() method, so that i can reuse?

Comment: in that case also, you will have to move the code i have written in RunWorkerCompleted to your gridDataBind() method..actually problem here is when you are setting too many items as itemsSource on your ItemsControl in one go, it will take time to render them... so what i have done is to set the ItemsSource first to ObservableCollection and then fill that collection one by one..so your View will not be blocked

Comment: I have say 10 times thanks you to you :) Inspire from your sample code and explanation. I am well understand the problem is occur because DataGrid have to render the row items and block the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in e.result at worker_DoWork and update UI at the  worker_RunWorkerCompleted.
in that case UI will be free when data will coming from database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should help you

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.Background,
  new Action(() => gridDataBind();));
```